# How to delete a particular UICollectionViewCell image. On pressing the button on the particular image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hello every one please help me in this:
As I took a `UICollectionView` in this `UICollectionView` I am adding the images, I want to delete a particular Image on button click.
the image I want to delete is having the close button on it.
How could I perform this task.
Note: 
1)Please see the image once before helping.
2)Please see the code I did for adding Image.

Image: 
[My Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqdHj.png)

```
//**** For image work ****
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *ident = @"Cell";
    OwnerPropertyCollectionViewCell *cell = (OwnerPropertyCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ident forIndexPath:indexPath];
    imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    if (indexPath.row ==0) {
        cell.Imgprofile_pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.btnImageCancel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add"];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *reconizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addphoto:)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:reconizer];

    }
    else {
        // get image not name
        cell.Imgprofile_pic.image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.btnImageCancel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close"];

    }

    return  cell;
}
// To add image:
-(void)addphoto:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)reconizer
{
    imageHelper = [UIImagePickerHelper new];
    [imageHelper imagePickerInViewController:self WithSuccess:^(UIImage *image) {
        imgView.image = image;
        [imgArray addObject:image];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
    NSLog(@"Image added successfully");


}

// What to code for delete image:
- (IBAction)btnCancelButtonAction:(id)sender {


    NSLog(@"Delete button pressed");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a tag value as a cell index path for your selected delete button.(ex : for first row button tag will be 0) 
then remove that image from your array. Then reload your UICollectionView

```
[imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: thanks mam, but I am a still bit confused. but I am working on it thanks .

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the following lines

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.yourCollectionView];  
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.yourCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

in this way you get the indexpath of the item and then

```
[YourImageArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
[self.yourCollectionView reloadData];
```

If need any help ask me

Comment: hey thanks, does I have to add this code in button's action?? like this: - (IBAction)btnCancelButtonAction:(id)sender {
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];
   
    [imgArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Delete button pressed");
    

}

Comment: Yes  paste this coding in Button action and after that it it have any problem then ask me

Comment: if this not work then give the Tag to the button.Like this take one Outlet of button cell class link the button with that outlet and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method Give the tag like this `cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.item`

Comment: sir I did the same as you told, and I added 3 images, but when I tried to delete one of the image the error come <*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]: range {13835058055284260886, 1} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'>

Comment: the reason is that you did not get the proper index